# Performance required on select query

Tags: sql, performance, select, optimization, informix

Consider the following Table_A and Table_B:

```
Table_A
ID  |A_Field_1
1   |10
2   |11
3   |12
```

Table_B:

```
ID  |B_Field_1
1   |500
1   |510
1   |520
2   |550
3   |530
```

I need to write a query where in to fetch the `ID` and `A_Field_1` for values in `Table_B` that don't have `B_Field_1` values of 520 or 530.

OUTPUT:

```
ID  |A_FIELD_1
2   |11
```

My current query is as follows:

```
SELECT ID,A_Field_1 
from Table_A
where ID not in (select ID from Table_B where B_Field_1 in (520,530))
```

This works but can someone provide a better performance based query; as in the above query the `select ID from Table_B where B_Field_1 in (520,530)` inner query is large and corresponds to a growing table.

Comment: @AmitSingh It's there in the tags: `[tag:informix]`

Comment: What indexes are there in these 2 tables?

Comment: @AmitSingh yes it is informix

Answer (score 2):

Try this one -

```
SELECT
      Id
    , A_Field_1
FROM Table_A a
WHERE EXISTS(
          SELECT 1
          FROM Table_B b
          WHERE B_Field_1 NOT IN (520, 530)
               AND b.Id = a.Id
     )


SELECT
      Id
    , A_Field_1
FROM Table_A a
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
          SELECT 1
          FROM Table_B b
          WHERE B_Field_1 IN (520, 530)
               AND b.Id = a.Id
     )
```

Comment: Yes this is correct, I didn't read the question correctly. Will remove my answer so as not to cause confusion. An index on TABLE_B on both columns will also assist subquery performance.

Comment: @Devart: This isn't equivalent though to the OP's query. It will return `id=1` for example. A `NOT EXISTS` would be.

Comment: @ypercube, this queries is equal.

Comment: Can you confirm if the 1st query will work. As per the example,<br>
1|500<br>
1|510<br>
will be considered as candidates and ID 1 might be an output which is not intended

Comment: @JMJ, these requests are equivalent, but I prefer the first query style.

Answer (score 2):

You can try like this also

```
SELECT
      Id
    , A_Field_1
FROM TABLE_A A
INNER JOIN
(
     SELECT
           Id
         , COUNT(CASE WHEN B_Field_1 IN (520, 530) THEN 1 END) AS ValidId
     FROM Table_B
     GROUP BY Id
) b ON A.Id = b.Id AND b.ValidId < 1
```

Comment: @Devart thanks for your edit to make my answer look good...@Devart can you teach me how to analyze the query like numberofscan and number of operation and how mcuh time it take

Comment: To make your queries to look cleaner, I suggest to use our free on-line SQL formatting service - [SQL Format](http://www.sql-format.com/).

Concerning optimization and analysis of queries, there are many books. I recommend you to get acquainted with [Itzik Ben-Gan's books](http://tsql.solidq.com/)